# Is Validation a SemiGroup/Monoid : using |+| does not work

Tags: scalaz

I was uder the impression that Validation could be used as a Monoid/SemiGroup
I tried the following code under scala 2.9.2 and scalaz 7 snapshot

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val success1 = 1.success
val success2 = 2.success

val failureA = "A".fail
val failureB = "B".fail

success1 |+| success2
<console>:16: error: diverging implicit expansion for type scalaz.Semigroup[scalaz.Validation[Nothing,Int]]
starting with method validationSemigroup in trait ValidationInstances
              success1 |+| success2
              ^
<console>:16: error: value |+| is not a member of scalaz.Validation[Nothing,Int]

              success1 |+| success2
```

I was expecting a `Success(3)`

then

`failureA |+| failureB` gives
`res1: scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Nothing] = Failure(AB)`
as expected

and

`success1 |+| failureA` fails as expected with

```
<console>:16: error: diverging implicit expansion for type scalaz.Semigroup[scalaz.Validation[Nothing,Int]]
starting with method validationSemigroup in trait ValidationInstances
              success1 |+| failureA
              ^
<console>:16: error: value |+| is not a member of scalaz.Validation[Nothing,Int]

              success1 |+| failureA
```

Why `|+|` on `Success` does not work ? Is it a bug or did I miss something here

Answer (score 3):

It works like this:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val success1 = 1.success[String]
success1: scalaz.Validation[String,Int] = Success(1)

scala> val success2 = 2.success[String]
success2: scalaz.Validation[String,Int] = Success(2)

scala> val failureA = "A".fail[Int]
failureA: scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int] = Failure(A)

scala> val failureB = "B".fail[Int]
failureB: scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int] = Failure(B)

scala> success1 |+| success2
res0: scalaz.Validation[String,Int] = Success(1)

scala> failureA |+| failureB
res1: scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int] = Failure(AB)

scala> success1 |+| failureA
res2: scalaz.Validation[String,Int] = Success(1)
```

You did not specify the type of the left element (`Failure`) in your first two `val`'s. That is why `Nothing` was inferred. Apparently, `Validation` has a `Semigroup` instance if the left element is a `Semigroup` (`Nothing` is not, `String` is). Here's an [instance](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Validation.scala#L364).

**UPD:** Also, as you see, `Semigroup` instance gets the first `Success` instead of using the `Success`'es `Semigroup` instance. I see, there is a method [`append`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Validation.scala#L77) in `Validation`, which requires both left and right elements to be `Semigroup`s and uses both instances:

```
scala> success1 append success2
res6: scalaz.Validation[String,Int] = Success(3)
```

Don't know, why it is not used in `Validation`'s `Semigroup` instance. Created a [pull request](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/101) to change this behavior.